# Non-existent file in limbo prevents push to remote branch (Bazaar VCS)

Tags: push, bazaar, filenames

I use Bazaar VCS to version files locally on my notebook. When im in the office I merge the changes to a repository on a windows share and also push all the files there (for backup reasons).

My Problem:

The last push resulted in an error, because I added a file with a very long filename (I had that problem before ... python doesn't like long filenames). So I removed the file (I didn't need it anyway) and forgot about the problem for a while, because commiting still worked fine.

The next time I wanted to push my new revision I got a new error:

```
bzr: ERROR: [Error 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: u'//path/to/remote/branch/.bzr/checkout/limbo/new-8/loooooooongfilename.xls'
```

translation:

```
bzr: ERROR: [Error 3] The system can't find the following path:
```

What I've tried:

- Deleting the limbo folder--> limbo folder doesn't exist
- Create the missing path with a dummy-file --> bazaar locks the branch --> unlock --> same problem as before
- bzr check --> Everything is fine --> No success
- bzr reconcile --> No success

Thanks for reading ;o)

Comment: The path in the error message got messed up:
u'//path/to/remote/branch/.bzr/checkout/limbo/new-8/loooooooongfilename.xls

The push worked before and commit still works, so no problem with the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bzr revert` (possibly with `-r 1234` to a specific version). Try it first on the specific file:

```
bzr revert -r 1234 path/to/myFile.php
```

Comment: Nice, That did the trick! Thanks! As I do not need the file (garbage that got versioned unintentionally) reverting didn't harm anything.